# How to get count from subcollection firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a structure like this:
'items/itemid/type/typeid'

So I want to count all the docs 'type' and get the value in a `Text`.

I am struggling to do this when I have subcollection, but with only one collection it's no problem.

I use this when it is only one collection: `fb.instance.collection('items').snapshots();` with a `Streambuilder`.

Comment: Are you saying you need help building a reference to a subcollection? Once you have that, it works exactly the same as a reference to a top-level collection.  You need to know the name of the document `itemid` in order to build it.

Comment: Hi, so I need to know the itemid for it to work? Then I think it is not possible to do it the way I want it. Maybe I need to structure it another way.

Comment: Why don't you know the value of `itemid`? If you don't know, why not store it then?

Comment: I know the value of `itemid`. But maybe the way I thinking of it's not the way to do it. What if I want to count the documents `itemid`. How can I do that when there also is a subcollection?